# Real-time video to array

Tags: arrays, opencv

I want to convert a real-time video to array. First, I want to extract the RGB video to frame-by-frame. Then, each frame will be converted to array. Can anyone help me with that? For now this is the code I am using. Thanks in advance!

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    #gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Your code already reads images from a camera and makes each one into an array called `gray`  - if you uncomment that line. What's the problem, please?

Comment: I want to send each frame via terminal command line by converting each frame into an array. Would you think that's possible?

Comment: This isn't making sense! You want to send each frame of video as an array (?) to who (?) using a Terminal (why?)

Comment: Okay. So I am performing a face detection on a jetson nano board. Now, Everytime the system detects a face, it will send the frame (which contains a face) to a windows pc using the terminal by using USB to TTL and PuTTy.

Comment: USB to TTL? Do you mean down a serial link?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. So instead of sending the frame directly. Since frames consist pixels, I need to convert frames to array and send the array.

Comment: I still don't get it :-) You have a PC, running Windows and you use Putty to connect to a Jetson over a serial link. You run Python scripts on the Jetson by typing them into your Putty sessions. You want the Jetson to suddenly send an image to the PC without the PC expecting it in the middle of your Putty session? And you never mention Putty or serial or Jetson in your question?

Comment: Okay. So I have a jetson nano board with face detection running independently with its own Operating system. On the other hand, I have my windows pc running independently also. In order to create a communication between the two, I use a USB-to-TTL converter so that I can send data from my jetson nano to my windows pc.

Comment: Now, from the real-time face detection that is running in the jetson nano, I want to extract each frame whenever the system detects a face. After extracting frames with face(s) detected, the frame(s) are going to be converted to an array so that I can send it to my windows pc. I want to perform a face recognition separately from the face detection that is why i need to send each frame by converting it to an array.

Comment: I never mention, putty or serial or jetson in my question because I want to focus on extracting the frames first and coverting in into an array first. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Both `frame` and `gray` are already Numpy arrays.